# Не отправляется email

Tags: php, email

Добрый день.

На сайте не отправляется email.
mail не работает. Пробовал SwiftMailer - тоже нет.
В чём может быть причина и как отправить сообщения и вложения?

Спасибо.

```
    --------------------------------
    $to      = 'to@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: from@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
-------------------------------------------
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
--------------------------------------------
require_once 'mail/lib/swift_required.php';
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport());

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Order Entry') // Message subject
                   ->setTo(array('maestrotwors@gmail.com' => 'Eric Hilse')) // Array of people to send to
                   ->setFrom(array('agent.p.24.ru@gmail.com' => 'PAi Order Entry'))
                   ->setBody('1234567890', 'text/html'); // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                   //->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'design.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier
                   //->attach(new Swift_Message_Attachment(new Swift_File($file), $filename));
    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message))
        $success = true;
    else
        $error = true;
    ------------------------------------
```

Все эти варианты не работают. Если брать mail, то на других сайтах она работает. Прочитал, что может не быть smpt сервера или подкл неправильно. Что с этим можно делать?

Comment: Логи в студию, плиз )))

Comment: Посмотрите вот это: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Если пишите под linux, проверьте sendmail, хотя емнп, то в linux функция не использует mta, но тут я могу ошибаться, последний раз отправлял так письма пару лет назад.